# Batch-import folder of images into a Google Slides presentation

Tags: images, google-slides

I have a large folder of images (PNGs) that I would like to convert to a Google Slides presentation (one image per slide).  Currently, I have found only two workflows that can automate this process:

**Workflow 1**  (*only if on a Windows machine*):

1. Use Powerpoint to batch import the images into a photo slideshow
2. Save the Powerpoint slideshow and upload to Google Drive
3. Convert to Google Slides.

This workflow doesn't work on a Mac, however, because Powerpoint for Mac inexplicably does not have the "batch import images into a photo slideshow" functionality. So:

**Workflow 2** (*if on a Mac*):

1. Use Keynote to batch import the images
2. Export as a Powerpoint file
3. Upload the Powerpoint file to Google Drive
4. Convert to Google Slides

Both of these workflows seem absurdly cumbersome to me (especially the second one), but I have been unsuccessful at finding a simpler way to turn a bunch of images into a Google Slides presentation.  Surely something as simple as this can be done, right?

Comment: You can also use LibreOffice to batch import images, making each image a slide. Open LibreOffice Impress, and click "Insert", "Media", "Photo album".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a Google Slides add-on for this: [Slides Toolbox](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/slides_toolbox/994552357682).

It allows you to select multiple photos at once from Google Drive and imports them each as a new slide.

No idea who the developer is but it works for this task, it has other features I have not tried.

Comment: Agreed. Slides Toolbox works just fine for this. Create a slideshow and then in the menu select Add ons and install the Slides Toolbox addon. Then select the addon and select Import Tools

Comment: Beware, the app needs these permissions: "See, edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files".

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the app script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/image-slides

Its flexible if you know how to fine-tune it using JavaScript.

Comment: The JavaScript you just shared is works pretty well for creating a new slide per image. Do you know how to insert these images to existing slides? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to find a way to upload images to Google Slides using Python. I created a program that uploads images to Google Cloud Storage; creates a signed URL for them; then uses that URL to import images into Google Slides. It's available [here](https://github.com/kburchfiel/google_slides_image_uploader) under the MIT License and may be a helpful tool/resource.